# Best way to avoid transactions that create a new smart contract before submitting it

Tags: metamask, dapps, nodes

We are creating a permissioned network (using Besu) where anyone can create and submit transactions.  In this context, the writer nodes need to verify that these transactions are not creating new smart contracts.

To solve this problem, I think I can create a web server that receives transactions from anyone. This web server will check the "to" field (0x0) and submit it to the blockchain network or not. Is it the better way to deal with it?

Comment: What if somebody hacks your server? Or attacks it with DDoS? Or the cloud service that you're using goes to maintenance? If your network cannot be accessed directly through Ethereum nodes but only via an HTTP server, that this is not a decentralized network.

Comment: If you can configure the network to only allow transactions to a specific address, you could deploy a smart contract to that address which proxies all calls. You might be able to find a library online to do this. Otherwise it's a bit of work using assemble delegatecall and filtering out the actual `to` address from the calldata. You would avoid running a server though.